# Считывание местоположения мышки

Tags: jquery

Есть код:

```
$('#a1').mousedown(function(){
$(this).mousemove(function(e){
    s_mouse_y = e.clientY;
    $('#a3').text(s_mouse_y);
});
});
```

Действие mousemove сохраняется, когда я отпускаю кнопку мыши. Как исправить?

**Обновление**

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии считывалось местоположение мышки, а при ее отпускании прекращалось.

Comment: объясните, что именно вы хотите сделать и зачем вам два события для одного элемента?

Comment: хочу, чтобы при нажатии считывалось местоположение мышки, а при ее отпускании прекращалось

Comment: @PicanTo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Взводите флаг вне событий, и по его значению меняйте логику обработчика mousemove. Ни к чему каждый раз события вешать/снимать заново.
Как-то так, например:

```
var active = false;

$('#a1').mousemove(function(e){
    if(active) {
        s_mouse_y = e.clientY;
        $('#a3').text(s_mouse_y);
    }
}).mousedown(function(){
    active = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    active = false;
});
```